# Mono WCF Discovery / Mono Zeroconf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mono, zeroconf

I am trying to implement a discovery feature in Mono.

The goal is a service running a .NET application with Mono on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian. This application should support a discovery feature.

First I tried it with the WCF Discovery Approach:

```
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
```

This works perfectly in .NET but does always throws an `InvalidOperationException`:

> Contract 'TargetService' is not implemented in this Service '....'

After some investigation, I figured that this is a Mono problem.

In this post:
[Is there any way to use WCF Discovery in mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167309/is-there-any-way-to-use-wcf-discovery-in-mono) They implemented a discovery with Mono.Zeroconf.

So I tried the Mono.Zeroconf approach:

To get it work I compiled the Mono.Zeroconf sources by my self, from here: https://github.com/mono/Mono.Zeroconf.
This worked perfectly in a Windows environment with Bonjour installed.
But the provider for Avahi (which is the Linux equivalent for Bonjour) is outdated.
I managed to compile it anyway, but it does throw some strange exceptions when running under Raspbian / Mono.

So I can not find a solution to discover my Mono project running on a Linux machine from any other (Windows or Linux) environment.

Does anyone have a solution for one of the problems above or a completely new approach?

As long as I can implement it in .NET and run with Mono I am happy to use every solution out there.

Comment: Your closest hope is to show us what is the exact issue of "I managed to compile it anyway, but it does throw some strange exceptions when running under Raspbian / Mono".